# Vowpal Wabbit: question on weight of interaction features

Tags: feature-engineering, vowpalwabbit

In VW, the format for feature namespaces is shown below:

> Label [Tag]|Namespace Features |Namespace Features ... |Namespace
> Features Where:
>
> Namespace=String[:Value]

and an example is:

> 1 1.0 |MetricFeatures:3.28 height:1.5 length:2.0 |Says black with white stripes |OtherFeatures NumberOfLegs:4.0 HasStripes

Notice that the |MetricFeatures namespace has a higher weight than 1 (3.28). Based on the above example, if I create some feature interactions, say between the M and the S namespaces with `-q MS`, does the new feature namespace that is the cross product of the two original ones have an importance weighting of 1 by default? Or would it inherit the product of the two importance Values (in this case 1*3.28 = 3.28)?

And is there a way to modify the weight of the feature interactions manually? E.g. say MetricFeatures has an importance weight of 1, can I have the features generated by the quadratic interaction of MetricFeatures**X**Says have an importance weighting of *x*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to individually weight interactions.

---

The namespace weight is processed at parse time, so when reading in the features of that namespace they are multiplied by the weight.

This can be verified by using `--audit`:

```
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = data.txt
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
0
    MetricFeatures^height:146807:4.92:0@0   MetricFeatures^length:38580:6.56:0@0    Says^black:100768:1:0@0 Says^with:163314:1:0@0  Says^white:106708:1:0@0Says^stripes:112832:1:0@0    OtherFeatures^NumberOfLegs:146847:4:0@0 OtherFeatures^HasStripes:229154:1:0@0   Constant:116060:1:0@0
1.000000 1.000000            1            1.0   1.0000   0.0000        9

finished run
number of examples = 1
weighted example sum = 1.000000
weighted label sum = 1.000000
average loss = 1.000000
best constant = 1.000000
best constant's loss = 0.000000
total feature number = 9
```

`MetricFeatures^height:146807:4.92:0@0` -> 3.28 * 1.5 = 4.92

Comment: thanks, and I confirmed that the weights of the interaction features under separate namespaces are multiplied by each other. For example, with ```-q ab``` and ```vw.learn("1 |a:3.1 x y |b:2 e f")``` with audit I see ```a^x*b^e:150563:6.2:0@0```. -> 3.1*2 = 6.2.